# How can I add only unique values to an anonymous array used as a hash value?

Tags: perl, hash

**EDIT** Sorry I forgot the most important part here. Each key *can* have more than one value. Apologies to those who already answered. `print` and `join` will be used later to print multiple values for `$key` on a single line.

In the example code below, assuming that the value `$keyvalue` is constantly changing, I am attempting to use a single line (or something similarly contained) to test and see if the current `$keyvalue` already exists. If it does, then do nothing. If it does not, then push it. This line would reside within a while statement which is why it needs to be contained within a few lines.

Preserving order does not matter as long as there are no duplicate values.

```
my $key = "numbers";
my $keyvalue = 1;

my %hash = ($key => '1');

push (@{$hash{$key}}, $keyvalue) unless exists $hash{$key};
```

I am not getting any errors with `use strict; use warnings;`, but at the same time this is not working. In the example above, I would expect that since the default value is `1` that the `$keyvalue` would not be pushed as it is also `1`.  Perhaps I have gotten myself all turned around...

Are there adjustments to get this to work or any alternatives that can be used instead to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Why bother with `push` if you are only ever going to save a single value? Just store the value. Skip storing if you already have one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way would be to put an anonymous hash at `$hash{$key}`. You only care about the keys of that anonymous hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %hash;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($key, $val) = split /\s*=\s*/, $line;
    $hash{$key}{$val} = undef;
}

for my $key ( keys %hash ) {
    printf "%s : [ %s ]\n", $key, join(' ', keys %{ $hash{$key} });
}

__DATA__
key = 1
key = 2
other = 1
other = 2
key = 2
key = 3
```

In the output, `key = 2` appears only once:

```
C:\Temp> h
other : [ 1 2 ]
key : [ 1 3 2 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
$hash{$key} = $keyvalue unless exists $hash{$key};
```

This will add the key,value pair `($key,$keyvalue)` only if the key is not already present in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You don't `push` values into a hash, since a hash needs key/value pairs and push only adds a value. In your expression you're treating `$hash{$key}` as an array reference to which you want to add a value. You just have to normally assign the value to the hash.